# Sign out the user if he lost the connection to backend database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've an Access application located on a server with backend tables.
The application recorded the users sessions; login if they started the app & logout if they closed it.
Sometimes the user lost the connectivity with the server and the application been restarted, the user remains login on the previous session because recording logout from a normal exit not occurred.
Is there a way to check on the backend file if a user is disconnected to record him as "signed out"?

Comment: _"I've an Access application located on a server with backend tables."_ - what **exactly** do you mean by that? Are you using Access, Excel, SQL Server, or ODBC/OLE-DB-based external tables?

Comment: "Is there a way to check on the backend file if a user is disconnected" - _possibly, **but not reliably**_, assuming these external tables are accessed (no pun intended) over an SMB share: the host server would get a list of active SMB connections and compare Windows usernames: obviously this won't work well outside of an AD domain environment (as usernames are machine-scoped and cannot be trusted).

Comment: @dai It's an Access frontend and Access tables as a backend.

Comment: Are you using SMB (i.e. serving the tables file from a Windows Network Share?

Comment: @Dai no, I'm not using SMB

Comment: ...so everyone is using the same computer?

Comment: @ Dai everyone is using his own computer, the Access app & its linked table are on a server just to share it with them, some users have edit permission & the rest are viewer only.

Comment: ...so how does  `MSAccess.exe` read the external tables when a user is on a different computer then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249007/discussion-between-ashraf-fouad-and-dai).

Comment: When you "share" a file or folder on Windows then you **are** using SMB (which is Windows File Sharing, as I said). So why did you say you were _not_ using SMB then?

Answer (score 0):

I think your referring to the *.laccdb file that access creates when someone is logged in to the BackEnd table.
Usually if it does list the same PC twice, once **all** PCs eventually logs out of the BE the *.laccdb should disappear if not, you can delete this file manually however, if the user looses connection ie the VPN goes down and doesnt log back in, then the BE will show that the PC is connected, in this case usually you can delete the *.laccdb.
If at any time you can not delete *.laccdb file Ask the user with the listed PC to log out. Worst Case if a user is not logged in but the *.laccdb exists the listed PC needs to reconnect and disconnect cleanly.

If the FE needs to check for connection to the BE it can be done but will not solve your issue, if the users PC crashed or VPN goes down whilst in the application then there very little that can be done because its too late, the damage is already done.

Comment: Actually I'm not depending on *.laccdb file, I'm using a code with a hidden startup form, when this form is loaded or unloaded. The problem if I lost the network connection the unload event gives an error & the exit process not recorded.